# MySQL alias and Table name

Tags: sql, mysql

I tried to execute the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `pd_cheque` as p WHERE `pd_cheque`.etype='pd_issue'
```

And it gave me the following error:

> #1054 - Unknown column 'pd_cheque.etype' in 'where clause'

After "some" experiments, I got the following query to work:

```
SELECT * FROM `pd_cheque` as p WHERE p.etype='pd_issue'
```

Why is that MySQL didn't let me execute the first query? 
Can a table name, when once assigned an alias, cannot be reference again with the table name?

Comment: to answer your question: yes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `pd_cheque` as p
WHERE `pd_cheque`.etype='pd_issue'
```

You have renamed the table using a table alias.  Everywhere else in the query, you need to use `p` to refer to the table.  The query no longer recognizes the original table name, because it has been renamed.

Table aliases are required for self-joins.  Consider:

```
select
from t join
     t
     on t.id = t.otherid
```

It just doesn't make sense without aliases:

```
select
from t join
     t tother
     on tother.id = t.otherid;
```

In addition, table aliases make queries easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Because when you define an alias for a table, as you did

```
`pd_cheque` as p
```

then you **have to** use it instead of the original table name.